# Butterknife binding views for floating action button and alert dialog together causes error

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I have an activity that contains a `FloatingActionButton`. Clicking on the button creates a dialog box with three edit text boxes to get input. I have used `@BindView` for all the three edit boxes.

```
@BindView(R.id.id_edit_text)
EditText idEditText;
@BindView(R.id.name_edit_text)
EditText nameEditText;
@BindView(R.id.desc_edit_text)
EditText descEditText;
```

Now I have to use

```
public void showAlertDialog(){
...
  AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
  View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout,null);
  ButterKnife.bind(this,dialogView);
...
}
```

Now for using `@Onclick` on my Floating Action Button

```
@Onclick(R.id.my_fab_button)
public void createAlert(){
...
    showAlertDialog();
...
}
```

I have to bind this view on the `OnCreate` method of the activity

```
Butterknife.bind(this)
```

this binding results in error as this statement tries to bind the views from the previously declared alert dialog which is incorrect.

How do I bind the Floating Action Button when I have already used Butterknife.bind call for alert Dialog?

Here is my layout file for the alert dialog

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/id_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/desc_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yo need to add `@optional` on every view declaration as follows

```
@optional
@BindView(R.id.id_edit_text)
EditText idEditText;
@optional
@BindView(R.id.name_edit_text)
EditText nameEditText;
@optional
@BindView(R.id.desc_edit_text)
EditText descEditText;
```

Comment: Optional annotation is giving error and I used Nullable annotation. Since the bind call for the alert Dialog is inside Onclick method of FAB, it throws error saying it cannot find the view